# Return the color of each cell in a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have some data that I'm visualizing in two different ways. The first is using seaborn.heatmap and the second using seaborn.kdeplot. What I would like is to use the color of each cell in the heatmap to color the corresponding kdeplot. Example:

```
this_matrix = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(100,100))
seaborn.heatmap(this_matrix)
```

What I would like is to return the color (rgb tuple) that is used in each cell of the above heatmap by seaborn.

Comment: `plt.get_cmap('rocket_r')(plt.Normalize()(this_matrix))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do what seaborn does:

```py
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = np.random.randn(5, 5)
norm = mcolors.Normalize()
data_normed = norm(data)
data_rgba = cm.viridis(data_normed)
```

Note that if you use a different colormap, you should change `viridis` and if you specify the `vmin` and `vmax`, you should pass those as arguments to `Normalize`

Comment: Your solution works great! As I am using a custom colormap, I went about it this way: `import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

vcenter = 0
vmin, vmax = this_matrix.min(), this_matrix.max()
normalize = mcolors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=vcenter, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
scalarmappable = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=normalize,cmap=my_cmap)
scalarmappable.set_array(K)`